# Connecting Outbound International Flight

Tags: usa, international-travel, jfk, delta-air-lines, virgin-atlantic

I have a flight connecting from my local airport to JFK where I will change from Delta to Virgin Atlantic. These were booked on different PNRs since there was a deal on the JFK to LHR flight. I've never changed carriers when connecting like that, moreso not on an internationa flight. Is there anything I should be aware of that will cause issues? The flight to JFK is 5 hours before the outbound flight and we're not checking bags. I just wanted to be sure there's nothing I am missing or would need to do for our passports/otherwise as I've already provided those details online.

Comment: I had similar booking several years ago: IND->ORD, then round trip ORD->LHR->ORD. My flight IND-ORD was cancelled. That was a 07:00 flight while the ORD-LHR was at 16:00. The carrier offered me an alternative that got me to ORD at 16:30. Not going to work. I was able to cancel my tickets for a full refund and rented a car for a one-way drive (about 3 hours). _If_ you can get to JFK _within those 5 hours_ by an alternate means, this will work for you. If not, I'd consider an alternate flight.

Comment: you booked those flights yourself separately?

Comment: You're flying JFK to LHR and you're not checking bags? That might cause you to undergo [extra security checks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45173/47309).

Answer (score 6):

> Is there anything I should be aware of that will cause issues?

If your outbound flight to JFK is cancelled or late enough that you end up missing the flight, you will need to pay a new ticket yourself as Delta has only the responsibility to carry you to JFK, not LON (some insurances may also cover it), for 5 hours it's unlikely but be mindful of that and of the timing too, to not miss it yourself.

---

Delta and Virgin Atlantic serve both Terminal 4 (I'd suggest you check your specific flight, if your flight lands in T2, you will need to pass through TSA again once arriving in T4 and again procedures will depend on the following)

Once you arrive in JFK, the procedure essentially boils down to if you can check-in online for your flight to London and what you want to do

If you can check online and both flights are in the same terminal, you can just stay in the gate area for your next flight and wait

If you can't, just exit the secure area, chill out and wait for the check-in to open and pass through TSA again

If you have checked in online, but want to leave the secure area, you can just exit while making sure you pass TSA early enough not to miss your flight

If you are at a different terminal, the above applies, except that you will exit the secure area to transfer

> To make your connection, follow signs for AirTrain. You will need to reclear TSA security once you arrive in your departure terminal.

From the [Port Authority](https://www.jfkairport.com/at-airport/connecting-flights)

Comment: *you end up missing the flight, you will need to pay a new ticket yourself* - technically that's correct, but the price matters, it's usually not full price, sometimes even 0. In the particular case of Virgin Atlantic they'll do it for free if OP manages to show up on the same calendar day. And even after that, he should definitely ask their staff. See 6.6 on https://help.virginatlantic.com/ng/en/policies/conditions-of-carriage/article-6.html - also @jnjustice